# Cat as a bicategory of monads over another category

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, large-cardinals, monads

Let's assume infinitely many Grothendieck universes exist. Let's call $\kappa$-Cat the bicategory of $\kappa$-small categories with anafunctors and anatural transformations. Now for any $\lambda$ and a $\lambda$-small 1-category $C$; we have a bicategory of monads $Mnd(C)$. Is there for all $\kappa$ a pair $\lambda$ and a $\lambda$-small 1-category $C$, such that $\kappa$-Cat $=$ $Mnd(C)$?

Comment: Wait. How do you get a "bicategory of monads" on a 1-category $C$ ? I now how to get a "bicategory of monads in a bicategory" or a "1-category of monads on a 1-category $C$ " but I don't see what category you are talking about here.

Comment: Taking 2-cells as natural transformations between underlying morphisms of monad morphisms, that satisfy; commutativity of a diagram as defined here https://github.com/agda/agda-categories/blob/master/src/Categories/Monad/Morphism.agda#L56, I think this should be the construction in https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/monad#the_bicategory_of_monads, I am trying to arrange it into bicategory in agda right now, to check that my understanding is correct.

Comment: A monad morphism for two monads on a fixed category $C$ is already a natural transformation, so there no natural transformation between morphisms. I don't fully understand the Agda code you sent me, but it seems to refers to the notion of morphism between a monad on $C$ and a monad on another category $D$. In this case there is indeed a notion of 2-cell, but then you are not talking about the category of monads on $C$, you are talking about the bicategory of monads in the bicategory $Cat$ of categories.

Comment: I wrote the code. It indeed refers to the notion of monad map that allows for 2-cells, as in Street "formal theory".

Comment: @fosco do do you mean 2-cells as in 2-cells, turning 1-category of monads on C into a 2 category? or 2-cells in the bicategory of monads in Cat sense?